# Updating list fragment with list adapter

Tags: android, listadapter, dialogfragment

Currently ran into an issue trying to update a list fragment with a dialogfragment input (or dummy input) everything compiles but don't see any change to the list.
Please let me know what you think.  Thanks.

```js
public class NewEventDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private List<GlobalClass> mItems;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        builder.setMessage("What Would You Like to Name the Event?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        mItems = new ArrayList<GlobalClass>();
                        mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whoiszzzzzzzzzzzzzzthis", "Adsdfdsdomg"));
                        mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whodsfzzzzzzzzzzzzzsdfsisthis", "Addsdfdfomg"));
                        mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whoisthzzzzzzzzzzzzzzsdfdsfis", "Addosdfsdfmg"));
                        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
                        MainTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new MainTabsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
                        // Attach the adapter to a ListView

                        adapter.addAll(mItems);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //setListAdapter(new MainTabsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.neweventdialog_fragment, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        return builder.create();

    }

}
```

```js
 private List<GlobalClass> mItems;        // ListView items list

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // initialize the items list
    mItems = new ArrayList<GlobalClass>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whoisthis", "Adsdfdsdomg"));
    mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whodsfsdfsisthis", "Addsdfdfomg"));
    mItems.add(new GlobalClass("Whoisthsdfdsfis", "Addosdfsdfmg"));

    // initialize and set the list adapter
    setListAdapter(new MainTabsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code for this '// Attach the adapter to a ListView ' where is your listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: ok I added          ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);          listview.setAdapter(adapter);        but findViewById cant be resolved

Comment: Your listview is still probably called R.android.id.list or something like that, change it to @+id/list

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have `ListView` in your layout `R.layout.neweventdialog_fragment` and bind this widget to your view in code, then setAdapter on it.

   ```
   View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.neweventdialog_fragment, null);
   ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView); // you bind to listView your widget
   listView.setAdapter(adapter); // you set adapter
   builder.setView(view);

   return builder.create();
   ```
2. When you wants to appear DialogFragment, you use `NewEventDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);`